# how to set default shell from sh to bash shell before script execution

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have shell script with certain commands being executed on alpine docker image.
currently, it uses `/bin/sh` shell to execute all commands.

the issue is , in the script, there is while loop which has counter. below code

```
i=0
cnt=15
while [ "$a" == "b" ] && [ "$i" == 15 ]
do 
  echo " Waiting for ..."
  sleep 2s
  ((i=i+1))
  ((cnt=cnt-1))
done
```

issue is on the line  `((cnt=cnt-1))` , getting following error

> sh: was: unknown operand /bin/sh: exit: line 178: Illegal number: -1

I was thinking of moving from /bin/sh to /bin/bash , can this be solution. if yes , how I can set the default shell as bash before executing the script. OR using the current shell only , how to resolve this counter issue.

please suggest

**EDIT 1**
the output of : `ls -l /bin/sh`

```
$ ls -l /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Nov 12 09:18 /bin/sh -> /bin/busybox
```

Comment: `it uses /bin/sh` what is "it"? How exactly do you execute the script? What is the shebang in the file?

Comment: executing script through gitlab ci yaml file. I haven't set any shebang line . Do you suggest setting shebang line ?

Comment: That's how you usually do it, yes.

Comment: `executing script through gitlab ci yaml file` Please _do not omit such important details_. Still, how exactly do you execute the script? Do you do `script: - i=0 - snt=15 -while ... etc` or you do `script: - ./yourscript` or you do `script: - /bin/sh ./yourscript`? Is the script executable? Please post `gitlab-ci.yml` file. What is the shebang in the file? What image exactly are you using? `:latest`? Have you installed bash? If you intend to use bash, why not use image with bash, instead of alpine?

Comment: Does Alpine Linux even include bash (by default, that is)?